# SonarQube not working in Jenkins after migration to OpenJDK 10

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, java-10

After upgrading project to `openJDK 10` we are getting this error in `Jenkins` build. We tried to run it locally with the same version of `SonarQube(6.7.5)` and `SonarJava plugin(5.7)`  where it worked fine. We didn't have any issues when running it with `openJDK 8`.

Jenkins console output:

```
Task :sonarqube FAILED
Task ':sonarqube' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
:sonarqube (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 69,5,main]) completed. Took 0.141 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Could you add more logs and a list of installed plugins? I think the real error message is above these few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube doesn't support running on Java 10 yet. You will have to stay at Java 8 for the time being. Note that you can run the analysis `sonar-scanner` or `mvn sonar:sonar` on Java 10 without issues. Only the server will not run.

Update: Latest 7.9 LTS version of SonarQube supports running on Java 11